# JSON load for json file issue

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a directory full of json files all formatted the same as .json files. I am looping through each file in the directory to access the json data, but when I try to load the data I get an error.

```
for json_file in file_list:
with open(backup_folder.joinpath(json_file), 'r') as f:
    json_loaded_data = json_file.load(f)
```

Running this code block returns:

```
AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
      1 for json_file in file_list:
      2     with open(backup_folder.joinpath(json_file), 'r') as f:
----> 3         json_loaded_data = json_file.load(f)
      4 
      5         date = json_loaded_data['tradeDate']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Example json file looks like this:

```
{
"settlements": [
    {
        "month": "MAR 19",
        "open": "2.650",
        "high": "2.744",
        "low": "2.638",
        "last": "2.647",
        "change": "+.059",
        "settle": "2.642",
        "volume": "225,563",
        "openInterest": "250,706"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_file` is just a string containing the name of the file. Try this instead:

```
with open(backup_folder.joinpath(json_file), 'r') as f:
    json_loaded_data = json.load(f)
```